# Terminologies for $nA=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Let $A$ be a matrix over a ring. Suppose $nA=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. I wonder if there are terminologies for such A and $n$.

Answer (score 0):

A way to express this is that $n$ is in the [*annihilator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_%28ring_theory%29) of $A$, or the set containing $A$ to stay completely in line with the linked to resource, when you consider the set of all matrices involved as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module.